# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to load applet from a .jar file

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

Sorry for this question but I'm a newbie to Java. I tried searching for similar problems, and I did find some answers, but none worked in my case, so here it goes:

I'm trying to load a java applet on a web page. The applet is supposed to be loaded from a .jar file (UCFApplet.jar), but I cannot get it to load no matter what.

Here's the html for the applet:

```
<applet id="UCFApplet" height="200" width="200" 
  code="com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet" 
  archive="UCFApplet.jar">
</applet>
```

The jar file is on the server, on the same folder than the html file that is trying to load it. Inside the jar file there's a  UCFApplet.class file on com/fujitsu/test/applet folder.

The error I'm getting on the Java console is the following:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_29
Using JRE version 1.6.0_29-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\PTMAIAJ
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------


load: class com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet
```

As you can see, I'm using jre 1.6.0_29 build 11, which, from what I get on the Oracle page, is the latest build. This happens on all browsers (IE 9, FF, Chrome).

I suspect it may have something to do with not being able to access the .jar file because if I change the html code to a dummy name such as archive="thisFileDoesNotExist.jar" it gives me the same error. But I don't really know what to put there in order to make it work.

Any idea about what I can be doing wrong ?

Thank you and best regards,

Joao Maia

Comment: Remove all the com... and just put only  code="UCFApplet"

Comment: Already tried that and it did not work... In fact, I tried code="UCFApplet", code="UCFApplet.class", code="com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet", and code="com.fujitsu.test.applet.UCFApplet.class". None worked... I always get the same problem. What's funny is that the applet works on Eclipse, but on the web page it gives the above exception... :(

Comment: By any chance you found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your descriptor seems to be correct, so try the following.

First check that browser can download the jar. Type the direct URL to jar file into your browser. For example if your html can be accessed by typing

`http://localhost/myapp/mypage.html`

type

`http://localhost/myapp/UCFApplet.jar`

If you can download the jar and it is identical to your jar continue.

Check the jar itself. Type in command line

`jar vft UCFApplet.jar`

and see output. You should be able to find your class:

`/com/fujitsu/test/applet/UCFApplet.class`

BTW do you know that applet tag is deprecated and is not supported by Opera and Chrome? To support all browsers you should use tag `object`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can donwload the jar file, and I can see my class when I do "jar vft". Thanks for the tip on the <object> tag. Is the syntax the same as the applet tag ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and the class is where it should be but the applet still gives the same error. Should i try to export the project as a runnable jar? I've the impression that won't work for applets, but might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning on tracing in the java control panel. It will then produce a log file in the following path that may help:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\sun\java\Deployment\log
```

In my case I had an error which only appeared when I turned on tracing, and which presented as simply a "ClassNotFoundException":

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
```

The applet loader was rejecting the jar because the zip file had a duplicate file entry. Strangely `appletviewer.exe` was able to load and run this jar fine.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you running behind a corporate proxy. According Oracle **`ClassNotFoundException`** is *"a common error that is seen if the proxy settings are not correct"*.

[image: proxy setting for Java]

See: [How do I configure proxy settings for Java?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml)